# display alert on each selected check box from a group of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes and I want them to do certain actions i.e display an alert box when they are checked and when one check box is checked, the others should be unchecked.

I've been able to get the second part to work where only one checkbox can be checked at a time but I can't seem to make the first part of displaying an alert box work.

js that ensures only one box is checked at any time:

```
function qtyBox(e) {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      c[i].checked = false;
     }
     e.checked = true;
 }
```

html:

```
<input class="qty" type="checkbox" id="pails" onchange="qtyBox(this)"/>Pails
<input class="qty" type="checkbox" id="liters" onchange="qtyBox(this)"/>Liters
<input class="qty" type="checkbox" id="gallons" onchange="qtyBox(this)"/>Gallons
```

Now all that's left is when Pails is checked,I want an alert box to display pails. when liters is checked, an alert box to display liters and when gallons is checked, an alert box to display gallons.

Comment: If you want a single option that is selected each time then you should use a radio button, not a checkbox.

Comment: @Terry—that will never catch on, there'd be no reason to use script…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get reference to the input. Just add:

```
var currId = e.id;
if(currId === "pails") alert("Pails");
else if(currId === "liters") alert("Liters");
else if(currId === "gallons") alert("Gallons");
```

so it become:

```
function qtyBox(e) {
   var c = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
   for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      c[i].checked = false;
   }
   e.checked = true;     
   var currId = e.id;
   if(currId === "pails") alert("Pails");
   else if(currId === "liters") alert("Liters");
   else if(currId === "gallons") alert("Gallons");
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons with a common name (e.g. *units*) and a click listener to do the alert. Add a value attribute for the value, an ID seems redundant:

```
<input class="qty" name="units" type="radio" value="pails" onclick="alert(this.value)">Pails
<input class="qty" name="units" type="radio" value="litres" onclick="alert(this.value)">Litres
<input class="qty" name="units" type="radio" value="gallons" onclick="alert(this.value)">Gallons
```

Though I'd delegate the listener to an ancestor element.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the onclick from the html - and just use something like this. However, if you want to use jquery would easier, but here is vanilla javascript solution. ( in a js file or wrapped in script tags )

```
(function(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('qty'); 
for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    var el = inputs[i];
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          inputs[i].checked = false;
         }
         this.checked = true
         alert(this.id); 
    });  
}
})();
```